# Serializing nested references to the same class in restkit

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I'm having a hard time getting serialization to work for an object where the object might contain other instances of itself.

For example the object:
Person
NSString* name
Person* mother
The JSON for this might look like:
{

```
"person": [

           {

            "name": "Blake Watters",

            "mother": {

                "name": "Jane Doe",

                "mother": {

                    "name":"Jane Smith",

                    "age":65

                }

            }

           }

        ]
```

}

I create the mapping:
    RKObjectMapping* personMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Person class] ];

```
[personMapping mapAttributes:@"name", nil];

[personMapping mapKeyPath:@"mother" 
           toRelationship:@"mother" 
              withMapping:personMapping];
```

If I perform inverse mapping on this so that I can serialize the object, I get a recursive mapping error as it continuously adding mappings.

The only answer I've been able to find is to set "serialization:NO" on the relationship.  This allows it to inverse and then serialize, but the serialization is of course, missing the mother object.

Is there a way around this?  Can I manually add this serialization back into the object after I've inverted it?

Edit:

Looks like adding it back in afterwards might be the way to accomplish this, as the following code seems to work.  Though it feels like there must be a better way.

```
// Map name
RKObjectMapping* nameMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Name class]];
[nameMapping mapAttributes:@"first",@"last", nil];

// Map person
RKObjectMapping* personMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Person class] ];
[personMapping mapAttributes:@"age", nil];
[personMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toRelationship:@"name" withMapping:nameMapping];

// Don't serialize mother
[personMapping mapKeyPath:@"mother" toRelationship:@"mother" withMapping:personMapping serialize:NO];

// Connect our mapping to RestKit's mapping provider
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:personMapping forKeyPath:@"person"];

// invert the mapping
RKObjectMapping* personSerialization = [personMapping inverseMapping];
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider 
                            serializationMappingForClass:[Person class]];
// Since mother wasn't serialized, add its relationship back in
[personSerialization mapKeyPath:@"mother" 
                 toRelationship:@"mother" 
                    withMapping:personSerialization];    
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:personSerialization 
                                                                forClass:[Person class]];
```

Thanks,
Adam